# Reverse of statistical mode using R

Tags: r

I am trying to match the Mode data with the Source Data which consists of 2 columns (`X` and `Y`). It works like this. Each element in 'Mode' is obtained as the statistical mode of 5 consecutive numbers in `X`. For the first 5 numbers its '312'. Similarly `319` is the mode for the next 5 numbers and so on. I would need to match the mode value `312` with its LAST occurrence in the first 5 numbers and then take the corresponding value of `Y`. Here: `400` for `312`, `225` for `319`, `325` for `315`.

Input:

```
Mode <- c(312,319, 315)

Source Data (2 columns X and Y): 
X   311 312 314 312 315 317 319 319 319 311 325 320 315 315 310

Y   100 200 300 400 500 300 450 375 225 300 445 455 345 325 256
```

> ```
> Output: 400, 225, 325
> ```

Comment: `Mode <- 312,319, 315` leads to the error message: `Error: unexpected ',' in "Mode <- 312,"`. Is this really R language? Please correct your code.

Comment: @ycw: I have edited the vector syntax to the right one now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks for the update. But to me it is still not reproducible. Not clear what do you mean `Source Data (2 columns X and Y)`, it does like any common data structure in R, such as a list or a data frame. There are lots of five-digit numbers in your X column, but there is no any description about this in your post. Because the entire post is unclear, there is nothing I can do.

Comment: @ycw: I have updated the question with more details. Source Data is a dataframe with 2 columns X and Y. The elements in the vector 'Mode' is the statistical mode of 5 consecutive numbers of column X. E.g: Mode of 311 312 314 312 315 317 is 312. Similarly, Mode of 317 319 319 319 311 is 319 and so on.. I would need to match each of the mode values (E.g. The first Mode value 312) with its LAST occurrence in the first 5 numbers (312 in row 4 of X) and then take the corresponding value of Y (400 in row 4 of Y). Here: 400 for 312, 225 for 319, 325 for 315. Please let me know if it makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your data

```
Mode <- c(312,319, 315)
# Using Z.Lin's data
X <- c(311, 312, 314, 312, 315, 
       317, 319, 319, 319, 311, 
       325, 320, 315, 315, 310)
Y <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 
       300, 450, 375, 225, 300, 
       445, 455, 345, 325, 256)
DF <- data.frame(X, Y)
```

#### solution

```
library(dplyr)
ans <- DF %>%
         filter(X %in% Mode) %>%
         group_by(X) %>%
         do(tail(.,1))

#       X     Y
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   312   400
# 2   315   325
# 3   319   225 

ans$Y
# [1] 400 325 225
```

Comment: This is more generic! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any inbuilt function that does precisely this (it seems like a rather niche requirement), but a combination of base functions can do the job, & you won't even need to calculate mode separately.

Data sample:

```
X <- c(311, 312, 314, 312, 315, 
       317, 319, 319, 319, 311, 
       325, 320, 315, 315, 310)

Y <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 
       300, 450, 375, 225, 300, 
       445, 455, 345, 325, 256)

DF <- data.frame(X, Y)
```

Function:

```
myFun <- function(DF){
  X <- matrix(DF[,1], ncol = 5, byrow = T)
  Y <- matrix(DF[,2], ncol = 5, byrow = T)
  LastPosition <- apply(X, 1, function(x){max(which(x == sort(unique(x))[which.max(table(x))]))})
  unlist(lapply(seq_along(LastPosition), function(i){Y[i, LastPosition[i]]}))
}

> myFun(DF)
[1] 400 225 325
```